# Using Ansible, How do I install multiple RPMs with yum at the same time?

Tags: python, ansible, yum

I would like to install multiple RPMs at the same time with yum. I have the list of items in the with_items array. Is there a way to concatenate it and install it in one go?

```
- name: Install MongoDB RPM
  yum: name={{ list | join(" ") }} state='present'
  with_items:
    - {'name': mongodb-org,         'file': mongodb-org-3.2.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm}
    - {'name': mongodb-org-mongos,  'file': mongodb-org-mongos-3.2.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm}
    - {'name': mongodb-org-server,  'file': mongodb-org-server-3.2.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm}
    - {'name': mongodb-org-shell,   'file': mongodb-org-shell-3.2.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm}
    - {'name': mongodb-org-tools,   'file': mongodb-org-tools-3.2.6-1.el6.x86_64.rpm}
  sudo: yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do this. The yum module is optimized for loops to install all items in one go.

From the [yum module docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/yum_module.html):

> When used with a loop of package names in a playbook, ansible optimizes the call to the yum module. Instead of calling the module with a single package each time through the loop, ansible calls the module once with all of the package names from the loop.

From the [loops docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#standard-loops):

> The yum and apt modules use with_items to execute fewer package manager transactions.

Comment: Strange, I got an error at the first run that package A depends on package B. With the second run the error went away. Thanks anyways.